# Information about ethical profile of companies

Tags: human-rights, crime

I would like to find as much information as possible about the ethical profile of major companies. I mean something like [this site](http://www.ethical.org.au) 
where you can search for a company and obtain a list of the crimes it is accused of, and/or the praises it receives for its good actions.
For the time being ethical.org.au was the only site I was able to find that does not require registration or paid subscriptions.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: While I think this is a good question, it doesn't fit in the scope of this site. It's nothing to do with politics.